# Typescript conditional mapped types based on field name

Tags: typescript, oop, types, interface

I have an interface called `IBlogFields` that contains a bunch of fields:

```
interface IBlogFields {
    title: string,
    description: string,
    body: string
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And another interface called `IBlogAttributes`:

```
interface IBlogAttributes {
    attributes: IBlogFields
}
```

I want to create a type that makes all fields optional except the `title` field:

```
interface IBlogAttributes {
    attributes: OptionalExceptTitle<IBlogFields>
}

type OptionalExceptTitle<T> = {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And `IBlogAttributes` would be like this:

```
title: string,
description?: string,
body?: string
.
.
.
```

All fields are optional except the `title` field, without manipulating the original `IBlogFields` interface.

Comment: Try this:`Partial<IBlogFields> & Pick<IBlogFields, 'title'>`

Comment: @BenWong thank you did not about the `Pick` type.